# Correlation of elements from two symmetric, positive definite matrices

Tags: correlation, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

> Suppose we have two n-by-n, symmetric, positive definite matrices (a.k.a. variance-covariance matrices). Are the elements always positively correlated?

For example, the following two has a correlation of 0.87.

\begin{bmatrix}
6.96461487 & -0.07257359 & -0.9801043 \\
-0.07257359 & 6.91825386 & -0.2198709 \\
-0.98010433 & -0.21987088 & 9.0856412 \\
\end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix}
7.106961 & 1.7414630 & -2.7030161 \\
1.741463 & 2.4653056 & -0.1420064 \\
-2.703016 & -0.1420064 & 6.6259570 \\
\end{bmatrix}

I simulated over 10,000 of such matrices and I still get positive correlation.

**Is there a formal proof for that? Or is there a specific example where the matrices would be negatively correlated?**

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553 here is a reference in mathjax for typing maths on this site.

Comment: If you have positive elements down the main diagonal and negative elements in the off diagonal, you have negative correlation.

Answer (score 0):

your basic variance - covariance matrix.

$\begin{bmatrix} \sigma_1^2 & cov_{1,2}\\cov_{1,2}&\sigma_2^2 \end{bmatrix}$

Which you could altertatively write as.

$\begin{bmatrix} \sigma_1^2 & \rho\sigma_1\sigma_2\\\rho\sigma_1\sigma_2&\sigma_2^2 \end{bmatrix}$

If $\rho< 0$ it represents negative correlation.

$-1 \le \rho \le 1$ the matrix is positive definite.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @doug, but that isn't quite what I am looking for. I should have been more specific in my question. I am looking for correlation between the elements of two matrices (A _ij_ vs B _ij_, _i_ is row, _j_ is column).